# Get value and element id from input on button click

Tags: jquery

I have many repeats of this code below where a value in the input needs a calculation made to it on button click.  Please can someone tell me how to get the value and replace it with a new one or get the id of the input element and I can update it.  I have tried various bits of code like this

```
alert($(this).parent().prev().attr('id'));
```

but am obviously missing something as the elements are not adjacent.  So clicking on the button must change the value in the input box. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input1" name="p1TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button1" type="button">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your correct answers.  Really appreciate them, and so quick too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code `alert($(this).parent().prev().attr('id'));` doesn't go UP into the appropriate `<td>` element, so it's looking for the `id` of the `<td>` itself.

Change it to the following, and it should work...

```
alert($(this).parent().prev().find("input").attr('id'));
```

Alternatively, I would recommend giving the `<input>` a specific **class** and referencing it like that instead...

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
     console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".myInput").attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="tr-odd">
      <th>Total Revenue</th>
      <td>
          <input id="input1" name="p1TotalRevenue" class="myInput" />
      </td>
      <td >
          <button id="button1" type="button">Test</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-odd">
      <th>Total Revenue</th>
      <td>
          <input id="input2" name="p1TotalRevenue" class="myInput" />
      </td>
      <td >
          <button id="button2" type="button">Test</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The advantage of using a class is that you can target a specific input, should there be more than one within your `<tr>`.  Otherwise you can ignore the class and simply use `.find("input")` instead of `.find(".myInput")`

Comment: Thank you freefaller.  I used your approach as I have another identical column being added to the existing and will need the distinction in classes.  That was great, thank you.

Comment: Exactly why I suggested it - glad I could help @Derek. Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope this one helps.

```
     $("button").on("click", function() {
           $(this).closest("tr").find("input").first().val("set");
     });
```

Comment: I think first isn't needed but should still work though.

Comment: Yep first() ist just some kind of security so that it would not affect more than one nested input field. But thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it by getting the `parentNode` of the `parentNode`.

```js
function getSomeValue() {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

function doIt(context) {
    context.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("input").value = getSomeValue();
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input1" name="p1TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="doIt(this)">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input2" name="p2TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button2" type="button" onclick="doIt(this)">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input3" name="p3TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button3" type="button" onclick="doIt(this)">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it is the context-variable of jQuery(selector,context):

```js
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
  const value = $( "input", $(this).closest("tr") ).val() 

  alert(value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input1" name="p1TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button1" type="button">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input2" name="p2TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button2" type="button">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-odd">
    <th>Total Revenue</th>
    <td>
        <input id="input3" name="p3TotalRevenue"/>
    </td>
    <td >
        <button id="button3" type="button">Test</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```